# What rights or permissiones does a user need to be able to run certain powershell commands in azure?

Tags: azure, powershell

Iam trying to determine the minimum user rights , roles I can assign a user just so they can pull information from Azure AD, etc.

Currently the commands I am looking into are : Get-AzureADDevice , Get-AzureADUser, Get-MsolDevice.

All documentation I find just lists uses, examples etc. but not rights and I am currently unable to test out a case by case from normal user up to admin to find which rights are required.

Comment: I know that you can create custom RBAC roles if you really awnt to lock it down. Perhaps you could start with this one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#directory-readers

Comment: Read this document of [Restrict member users' default permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions), you can prevent non-admin users from the directory access.

Comment: the RBAC roles and the directory readers might be, I just want a user that is able to read all info in the directory, but unable to change  anything. I might have overlooked that type of role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigned the [Global Reader role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#global-reader) to the user and tested one of the given commands (**`Get-AzureADUser`**) in the Question.

[image]

Tried to update the user but not possible due to the role permission restrictions.

[image]

**Note:** **`Global Reader`** - ***Can read everything that a Global Administrator can, but not update anything***.

#### Updated Answer:

Assigned the **Directory Reader Role** to the user and checked the workflow, able to get the information but not successful to update or do management work like updating/modifying the information using Azure Active Directory PowerShell Commands:

[image]

**Workaround Result**:

[image]

**Note**: **`Directory Reader`** Role - C***an read basic directory information. Commonly used to grant directory read access to applications and guests***.

Depending on your requirement, you can choose any of the above RBAC for the user.

Comment: I would first test Directory Readers role. It grants only Azure AD reading permission and those 3 commands which Victor provided should be included in that permission.