# Azure: How to lock down the 'Invoke-AzVMRunCommand' Powershell cmdlet?

Tags: azure, powershell, security, permissions, azure-runbook

We have a requirement to lock down our Azure environment as much as technically feasible. Using the 'Invoke-AzVMRunCommand' Powershell cmdlet, some of our users are able to remotely execute code on VMs that are behind several layers of abstraction. I've had a look through Custom IAM Roles to see if I can find the permission responsible for this, but I can only find permissions relating to Azure Automation, which I'm not sure if this falls under.

Does anyone have any insight on which permission would effectively disable this cmdlet?

Thankyou

I've created custom IAM roles with varying levels of permissions, but I'm looking to toggle off the specific permission for this cmdlet instead of blanket removing several at once.

Comment: Refer the solution provided here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71835695/what-rights-or-permissiones-does-a-user-need-to-be-able-to-run-certain-powershel

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question and I've finally found the relevant documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/run-command

> Limiting access to Run Command
> Listing the run commands or showing the details of a command requires the Microsoft.Compute/locations/runCommands/read permission on Subscription Level. The built-in Reader role and higher levels have this permission.
> Running a command requires the Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/runCommand/action permission. The Virtual Machine Contributor role and higher levels have this permission.
> You can use one of the built-in roles or create a custom role to use Run Command.